# Please help Identify these algae

Tags: botany, species-identification, microbiology, microscopy

Found this algae in a small stony stream that feeds a medium sized river. I can not identify either of the filamentous algae in this photo

[image: Algae]

Comment: A photo would help...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado sorry, just uploaded

Comment: Please add a location and the relative length /width. (and add a scale/let us know the magnification) . Thanks.

Comment: @theforestecologist, I do not know the relative size, but that is 40x magnification. I apologize all i have access to is my high school science lab

Comment: @theforestecologist This sample was from green algae growing on large granite rocks in a stream feeding the Dan river in North Carolina

Comment: @northcarolinaalgae you could mention that in the question.